# Is it possible to run pulseaudio in a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Arch Linux without any graphical environment?

Tags: arch-linux, audio, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio

I have a Rapberry Pi running Arch Linux ARM without any graphical environment. I want it to play a song every morning.

I have pulseaudio installed.

But when I use paplay, I get an error:

```
paplay test.mp3
Failed to open audio file.
```

The test file is:

```
file test.mp3
test.mp3: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
```

I have the following entries in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
# See /boot/overlays/README for all available options

gpu_mem=0
initramfs initramfs-linux.img followkernel

hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2

dtparam=random=off
max_usb_current=1
dtparam=audio=on
```

Can I play audio without having any graphical environment?

Answer (score 1):

paplay has no mp3 support, use ffplay instead. (or convert to flac first)

> ...I will not be adding support for MPEG Layer 3 (commonly known as MP3) ...

http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/

> paplay ... understands all audio file formats supported by libsndfile

https://linux.die.net/man/1/paplay

Comment: I am not getting the point of installing graphical stuffs (ffmpeg has installed wayland, gpu-drivers and those stuffs). Same goes for omxplayer! Do you know any player that can work without installing a graphical environment? I don't want to waste RAM and CPU power rendering graphical environment.

Comment: Either you did something wrong or arch has packaged ffmpeg wrong; no gui is required(, but libraries from gui's are required for things such as subtitles). If you want a lighter solution convert to FLAC as I mentioned.  https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/ffmpeg/